# Symfony form EntityType class

Tags: symfony

I am preparing a form for the user's choice of a game according to selected parameters. I am using the EntityType class.

Example:

```php
///...
-> add ('Age_of_years', EntityType :: class, [
    ' required '=> false,
    ' label '=>' Age from years: ',
    ' class' => Game :: class, 
    'choice_label' => 'Age_of_years ',
    ' expanded '=> true,
    ' multiple '=> false,])
```

Many games are assigned the same minimum age and when borrowing from the database, the same values ​​appear in the form many times. Surely there is a way to avoid it?

Comment: You should use the `ChoiceType` and create your own choice list (ages). On submission of the form you can use this data to sort your results.. If that is what you're meaning? Currently you're getting the whole `Game::class` (all games), hence, you have duplicates of the age field in your dropdown..

Comment: Yes, that's what I want to get. I was just thinking that maybe there is a magic way ;)  to use entitytype and get the result whithout duplications. Thank you.

Comment: You will need some sort of definitive constant list of ages. As the age may not exist yet in your list of games but the user can still select that age from your set list.

Comment: What i usually do is use the `ParameterBagInterface` and store an array in the *services.yaml* under the *parameters*, then use that within the form builder by injecting via the constructor with `use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ParameterBag\ParameterBagInterface;`